# Transparent navbar swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, navbar, alpha

1. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUCgE.png) is what the project currently looks like
2. And this is the code that I use

   ```
   func styleNavBar() {
   let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
   navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0)
   navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)]
   navigationBarAppearace.translucent = true

   navigationBarAppearace.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.3)
   navigationBarAppearace.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)}
   ```

I have tried to remove the following code, but then it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKoNj.png).

```
navigationBarAppearace.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

My question is, how do I get the `navbar` to fill up to the top? and still have the same look

Comment: Please do not post images of code, post the actual code.

Comment: try after removing code `navigationBarAppearace.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)`

Comment: @SunilSharma I just tried that, it works, but the navbar loses the transparent effect.

Comment: Try taking down your alpha to 0.1 and see what the result is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create an extension for `UIImage` which create image with solid color of specified size.
Keep this extension in any ViewController at class label

```
extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

then use the below method to customise your navbar

```
func styleNavBar() {
    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0)
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)]
    navigationBarAppearace.isTranslucent = true

    let colorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.3), size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 64))
    navigationBarAppearace.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, for: .default)
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code on my UINavigationBar to make it transparent. You can adjust it to your needs. In the picture there's a searchController in the titleView

```
if let topBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        topBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        topBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        topBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        topBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        topBar.translucent = true


    }
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Transparent navbar]